# sql select column names where the column is a key

Tags: sql

using this query,

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME <table>
```

how would i modify it to select only column names that are primary keys? or keys of any type?

Using the same type of select is prefered.

Comment: shouldn't matter if the OP is using INFORMATION_SCHEMA (except if his RDBMS didn't implement the ANSI standard)

Comment: @StuartAinsworth: there's an ANSI Standard for RDBMSs?! :) Polite requests: please don't use the term "relation" (and its derivatives) when you mean SQL and note that the SQL Standards are international and not just American. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Table_Constraints tc
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
        ON tc.TABLE_NAME = kcu.TABLE_NAME
            AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA
            AND tc.TABLE_CATALOG = kcu.TABLE_CATALOG
            AND tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE tc.TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

Comment: To which you can add AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY_KEY' to get only the primary keys. or 'FOREIGN KEY' for FKs, etc.